# RestKit.h never found in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I've tried everything to fix this issue but, despite about 100 'solutions' online, nothing has worked. I'm now worried that I'm altering core files without a clue what I'm doing and that something will ultimately render the entire project dead.

Is it a simple and safe procedure to re-install RestKit to the project by removing it from the podfile then adding it back in? Or is that wishful thinking?

**EDIT:**

Found a working version from 2 weeks ago
Copied it successfully
Still Builds
Installed Pod 'PageMenu' via the following addition to Podfile under existing lines.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'PageMenu'
```

Cleaned up the errors on PageMenu swift file.
**Build results in the RestKit.h file not being found.**

So guess something in my pod install is seriously killing my project.

Any further ideas? Thanks

Comment: yes, you can edit the pod file, then update, ensure you're opening the workspace

Comment: Thanks Wain. Unfortunately reinstalling didn't make any difference. I think the project is dead and will have to start again - has been 3 days already. I'd been running the project successfully from the workspace for more than 2 weeks until I had to add a pod.

Comment: then you should look at which version you were previously using and pin to that for the time being

Comment: Thanks. Even starting from scratch with previously working files hasn't changed the situation. I notice that the contents of the Pods/Frameworks folder are all red - is that normal?

Comment: also - the original structure had everything in format 'libAFNetworking.a' but now everything is in format 'AFNetworking.framework'. The entire Pods setup has altered significantly.

Comment: yes, you either need to upgrade fully or return to all of the versions you were previously using